# Exporting all values from workspace to excel or csv

Tags: matlab, export-to-excel

Is there some way to export all variables from workspace on to an excel spreadsheet or a csv file,  automatically.   I have 100 + variables,  and I do not want  to iteratively export one variable at a time,  referring each variable by name if possible.

Comment: If you have 100+ variables in the first place, you might want to take a second look at your code. In MATLAB code, often this means you're using multiple named variables where you should be using a single larger matrix, cell array, or struct to hold the data.

Answer (score 3):

You can write each variable to a different sheet in the spreadsheet:

```
S = whos; %// get all variables
xslfilename = 'savedFile.xslx';
for ii = 1:numel(S)
    cmd = sprintf( 'xslwrite( xslfilename, %s, ''%s'' );', S(ii).name, S(ii).name );
    eval( cmd ); %// not very happy with using `eval`...
end
```

Use [`whos`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/whos.html) to list all variables currently in workspace, and [`xlswrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html) to write each variable to a different sheet of the same xls file.

When reading the file you can use [`xlsinfo`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsfinfo.html) to get all sheets names

```
[status,sheets] = xlsfinfo( xslfilename ); %// get all sheet names = variable names
```

Now you can read each variable from each sheet using [`xslread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html).

Comment: Why are you not happy about the eval line?

Comment: `eval` is not a good practice. you can see a short taste of why [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7kmd5).

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you're looking for, but if you're trying to save the workspace in order to load it back to MATLAB later, use the `save` and `load` functions.